# Соответствующая платформа  для работы с данными SQL на C#

Tags: c#

На какой платформе автоматически генерируется соответствующий класс во время работы с базой данных SQL на C# (Мне сказали ntt или ett). Не могу найти ее. (Но не ado.net, здесь все сделаются вручную.)

Comment: не знаете?((

Comment: Я, например, вообще не понимаю вопрос....

Comment: для меня тоже не понятно.дали один задача и сказали что не использовать ado.net для работы с БД  использовать етот ett.framwork то ли ntt,где соответствующий классы автоматически генерируется,не надо все ето вручную зделать в ado.net.не как не магу найти етот.

Answer (score 3):

ett.framwork? Мб [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb399572.aspx)? Если так, то это не чистый ado.net, это праздничная обёртка над ним. Открываешь студию, создаешь проект, добавляешь в него [EDM модель](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb399739.aspx) и вуаля, классы готовы.

Comment: спасибо вам я етот хотел узнать

Comment: есть ли хорошие книги на русском по этой теме?????

Comment: По поводу книг сказать не могу. Сам учил по MSDN, ну и по форумам спрашивал когда что-то было не очень понятно.

Comment: окай понятно,спасибо вам